# How can I use dfs to produce topological sort?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

How can I use the depth first search function (dfs) to produce a topological sort?

This is my code:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.id = key
        self.connectedTo = {}

    def addNeighbor(self,nbr,weight=0):
        self.connectedTo[nbr] = weight

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

    def getConnections(self):
        return self.connectedTo.keys()

    def getId(self):
        return self.id

    def getWeight(self,nbr):
        return self.connectedTo[nbr]

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertList = {}
        self.numVertices = 0

    def addVertex(self,key):
        self.numVertices = self.numVertices + 1
        newVertex = Vertex(key)
        self.vertList[key] = newVertex
        return newVertex

    def getVertex(self,n):
        if n in self.vertList:
            return self.vertList[n]
        else:
            return None

    def __contains__(self,n):
        return n in self.vertList

    def addEdge(self,f,t,cost=0):
        if f not in self.vertList:
            nv = self.addVertex(f)
        if t not in self.vertList:
            nv = self.addVertex(t)
        self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(self.vertList[t], cost)

    def getVertices(self):
        return self.vertList.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vertList.values())



class DFSGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.time = 0

    def dfs(self):
        for aVertex in self:
            aVertex.setColor('white')
            aVertex.setPred(-1)
        for aVertex in self:
            if aVertex.getColor() == 'white':
                self.dfsvisit(aVertex)
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are different ways to obtain the topological sort of a given graph, the topological sort of a graph can be obtained using DFS with some bookkeeping. Of course, for there to be a topological ordering of a graph in the first place, the graph must be a directed acyclic graph (DAG). A way to know if a graph is a DAG is if you can find a vertex with no incoming edges.

A helpful visual I found from https://www.techiedelight.com/topological-sorting-dag/ [shows that a back edge creates a cycle in the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTl8L.png). In topological sort we are attempting to order the edges from largest departure time to smallest departure time.

The reason DFS works to find Topological sort is that if DFS is run on a DAG, the search will not find any back edges because there are no cycles by definition. That means there are no edges in a tree (U,V) where the finishing time of V is greater than the finishing time of U. DFS on a DAG has no back edges so all the edges U,V finish with U < V. Therefore, if we run through DFS and place our nodes that finished first into a stack, and then pop out the items and print them, we get the topological ordering.

Since this is simply DFS with an extra data structure, the runtime would simply be O(V + E).